# QML StackView showing error You cannot push/pop recursively

Tags: qt, qml, push, stackview

I have two QML files

Level1.qml and level2.qml

in main.qml,

```
    StackView {
        id: idMyStackView
        focus: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: Level1{
                focus: true
            }
    }
```

in Level1.qml

```
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        idMyStackView.push(idLevel2.qml)
    }
```

In this case I am getting error like

> W] (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:790) Warning: StackView: You cannot push/pop recursively!
> [D] (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:791) __recursionGuard (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:791)
> push (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:568)
> onCompleted (qrc:/setup/qml/setup_menu/setup_top/SetupTop.qml:250)
> __loadElement (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:825)
> __performTransition (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:911)
> push (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:605)
> expression for onCompleted (file:///C:/Qt/5.13.0/msvc2017/qml/QtQuick/Controls/StackView.qml:777)

Comment: Why are you pushing a second item on the stack during the operation of pushing the first item?

Comment: In some special cases I need to push Level2 on top of Level 1. Level2 has some dependency with level1. so pushing level2 only is not possible

Comment: did you try calling idMyStackView.push(idLevel2.qml) in your main.qml instead of Level1

Comment: *"Level2 has some dependency with level1"* - This sounds like a design flaw.